# Radiobutton list auto postback

Tags: asp.net, html

Ok, this is painful for me because yes, I've been coding ASP.NET after classic ASP days.  I've so lost the ways of regular HTML controls.

So, here's my scenario.

**1)** I have a list of radiobuttons on the page, regular old HTML buttons:

```
<div id="selectOptions">
    <form action="Checkout.aspx" method="post" target="_self">
 <ul>
     <li><label><input type="radio" name="rbRewardsSelectionGroup" id="rbtNoRewardOption" checked="checked" value="0" />None</label></li>

     <li><label><input type="radio" name="rbRewardsSelectionGroup" value='1' />Free Shipping</label></li>

     <li><label><input type="radio" name="rbRewardsSelectionGroup" value='2' />$100 Store Credit</label></li>

     <li><label><input type="radio" name="rbRewardsSelectionGroup" value='3' />$250 Store Credit</label></li>

     <li><label><input type="radio" name="rbRewardsSelectionGroup" value='4' />$500 Stored Credit</label></li>
 </ul>
    </form>
</div>
```

**2)** I need to add some javascript to force a postback if any one of these radiobuttons are selected, even the default selected radio button

**3)** I attempted to add a form and wrap it around the code.  I don't know if this will work because I think ASP.NET won't let you have more than one form on a page...or maybe that's just how it is for everyone?

**4)** Lets say it will work.  Ok so I click the radio button.  I send a request to Checkout.aspx and then in the code-behind I can grab that data and do a Request["rbRewardsSelectionGroup"] to get reference to that radiobutton group and then perform my server-side value checks...whatever I need to do.

I guess my question is am I going about this right with the way I have this setup currently?  I believe I've got the overall concept here outside of using ASP.NET based controls that do all this magic for you.

I don't want to get into why I'm not using an ASP.NET control for this particular piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2) With jquery, listen for the change event on the radio buttons and submit its parent form:

```
$("input[@name='rbRewardsSelectionGroup']").change(function(){
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
});
```

3) You can only have one form with a runat="server" property in asp.net

4) Yes, use Request.Form["rbRewardsSelectiongroup"] to get the value of the selection.

Comment: thanks for verifying all this.  Yea, it's the runat=server, forgot that...on the multiple forms issue.